# how to solve Google Charts loader.js can only be loaded once

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, charts

```
<script type="text/javascript">

google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
  google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);


  function drawChart() {

      var completed=parseInt(document.getElementById('completed1').value);
      var notcompleted=parseInt(document.getElementById('notcompleted1').value);

      alert(completed);
      alert(notcompleted);

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

      ['Task', 'Student'],
      ['Students Completed',     completed],
      ['Students Not Completed',      notcompleted],

    ]);

    var options = {
      title: ''
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart1'));

    chart.draw(data, options);
  }



</script>
```

this script is on my one page i am calling this page multiple times so in console it shows "Google Charts loader.js can only be loaded once."

Comment: Can you clarify some things please ? What do you mean by "i am calling this page multiple times" ?

Answer (score -1):

Move it to whatever file you use to preload all your other global functions etc.

example, i have mine the app.js (using angular)